Error when running app that uses tensorflow and pyinstaller
very good everyone, thank you for going into my problem, so I'm going to get to the point, it turns out that when I compile with pyinstaller everything works well, tensorflow is imported correctly, I don't see any problems when importing the h5 model either, the problem is when I want to do a prediction with .predict(), when you run the application with the predict line in the application, instead of opening the application an error window opens that says:
the code is very simple, this is it
import tensorflow as tf 
modelo = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5") 
numeros_variados = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 30), minval=2, maxval=11, dtype=tf.int32)
y_pred= modelo.predict(numeros_variados) 
print(y_pred) 

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
      y_pred= modelo.predict(numeros_variados)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    File "keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 119, in error_handler
    File "keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 506, in predict
    File "keras\src\callbacks\callback_list.py", line 126, in on_predict_batch_end
    File "keras\src\callbacks\progbar_logger.py", line 66, in on_predict_batch_end
    File "keras\src\callbacks\progbar_logger.py", line 95, in _update_progbar
    File "keras\src\utils\progbar.py", line 182, in update
    File "keras\src\utils\io_utils.py", line 98, in print_msg
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

I also attach a screenshot of the error, and thank you very much in advance
I need to be able to make the .predict() predictions without the error I described above appearing
I don't know if it helps but I get this message in the terminal every time I run the script
2024-05-02 13:48:11.074234: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
2024-05-02 13:48:14.790349: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
2024-05-02 13:48:22.773016: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:absl:Compiled the loaded model, but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. model.compile_metrics will be empty until you train or evaluate the model.

from the error, it looks like numeros_variados is None or an empty list...

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

some modules or function may not raise error when they can't read file but they may return None - and later code may have problem with None (ie. OpenCV has this problem - it has read() which returns None instead of raising error). Maybe you have similar problem.

Hello, thank you very much for responding! I will give you the 2 lines of code that allow this
  numeros_variados = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 30), minval=2, maxval=11, 
  dtype=tf.int32)
  y_pred= modelo.predict(numeros_variados)

lo que obtengo por consola es esto
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 608ms/step
[[0.00598791 0.00418885 0.00072821 0.00090043 0.00401254 0.00211928
0.01450225 0.00092229 0.0025662  0.00948683 0.00157091 0.00456388
0.06451724 0.00310891 0.00283157 ]]
There is more data inside the tensor but I have limited characters

As I said at the beginning, everything runs correctly as long as it is run with python main.py, the error is when I run the script with pyinstaller when it is compiled, so I don't think it is an error in the script but at the time of compiling, it's like If any file is missing from the tensorflow library

I can't make sense of your question. Please include all relevant context and provide a [mcve] extracted from your code. The error itself is hopefully clear, you'll find hundreds of questions about similar errors.

sorry for not being clear enough, the code is very simple, this is it
import tensorflow as tf modelo = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5") numeros_variados = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 30), minval=2, maxval=11, dtype=tf.int32) y_pred= modelo.predict(numeros_variados) print(y_pred)
when executed with python it works normally, but when compiled with pyinstaller it gets the error that you already know
